# Where and how to start to understand Monero?

Tags: monerod, blockchain, cryptonote, cryptonight

I'm a newbie and I would like to know more about Monero and the technology behind it.

What is a good starting point to learn more about Monero? Website, wikis, books?

Thank you so much for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that, at this time, the best starting point to learn all about Monero is [Mastering Monero: The future of private transactions](https://masteringmonero.com/). The book covers all the aspects behind Monero and gives you all the useful things to understand Monero.

As stated:

> This book contains everything you need to know to start using Monero
>   in your business or day-to-day life, even if you've never understood
>   or interacted with cryptocurrencies before.

Apart from that, you can find a lot of useful resources on the web and you can start reading [the resources section](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/) on the official **getmonero.org** website.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's like so interesting. I'll go to take a look.